# Cómo conectarse a MySQL sin tener que especificar la ruta completa

Tags: shell, macos, terminal

Desde que instalé MySQL, solo me permite conectarme de esta forma:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u user -p
```

quisiera saber cómo puedo conectarme de esta otra manera:

```
mysql -u user -p.
```

Sin tener que especificar la ruta completa, porque es un poco incomodo. Alguien que sepa que debo hacer para cambiar la manera para conectarse a MySQL.

Estoy en Mac OS, tengo la versión 5.7.21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1** puedes hacer un enlace simbólico al ejecutable de mysql dentro de la carpeta `/urs/local/bin`esta ruta debería estar en el path y cualquier comando que escribas si existe ahi no hace falta ponerle ruta completa

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

**2** también puedes agregar `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` al path

```
$ sudo nano /etc/paths
```

la forma 2 es recomendable si vas a usar `mysqldump` y otras herramientas q estan en el bin de mysql

**3** agregar al path sólo en tu perfil de consola: busca un archivo `.profile` o `.bash_profile` en tu carpeta `home` de usuario lo editas y le pones la siguiente línea al final:

```
PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:"
export $PATH
```

La forma 3 es la menos intrusiva, la 2 es global (pide contraseña admin), la 1 es generica para un solo ejecutable (también pedirá permiso admin)

Comment: Gracias amigo..